# MAUI Window already created on specific devices

Tags: .net, maui, .net-8.0

I'm getting a weird issue on my dotnet MAUI app, it works great for me, the issue doesn't run for any other phone but one person's One Plus.

[AppCenter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUNOR.png)

I can't figure it out and I don't see any other issues posted online for this

I don't know what to even attempt other than remaking the entire app

Comment: please do not post errors as images, and please do post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason there is no "relevant code" to this, the app error I only get on specific devices and the error is on AppCenter. There is no code of mine that is causing errors that I can provide. Please see the error and you will understand.

Comment: The screenshot is illegible.  Please post the relevant info **as text** in your post

Comment: I don't see how it is illegible, that is all the information I have as well, posting it as text won't make it any different

Comment: @Jason that is legit the only little error log I have for this issue, posting it as text and posting it as an image won't make a difference.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: @Jason I can understand that, but uploading the error as text in this case won't give any more information than that image will give.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have just seen this issue on Android Maui release candidate 1. I can reproduce it for myself by backgrounding the app then clicking on the app icon on the home page. If I click on the already open window (||| menu) it doesn't crash. I am using Android 11 Samsung Galaxy S20

Answer (score 6):

Same here with MAUI 8 preview. I can see the same error in the AppCenter with that OnePlus 8 device (Android 11), but I can't reproduce it.

### Stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Window.Microsoft.Maui.IWindow.Created()
Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.AppHostBuilderExtensions.<>c.<OnConfigureLifeCycle>b__2_0(Activity activity, Bundle bundle)
Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<OnPostCreate>b__0(OnPostCreate del)
Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents.LifecycleEventServiceExtensions.InvokeLifecycleEvents[OnPostCreate](IServiceProvider services, Action`1 action)
Microsoft.Maui.MauiAppCompatActivity.OnPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
Android.App.Activity.n_OnPostCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState)
Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0)
```

### Workaround

- Override the MainActivity.cs/OnPostCreate method
- Call `base.OnPostCreate(savedInstanceState)` in a try catch block.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you this workaround worked very good.